# Ansible - Variable precedence fails when hosts are the same

Tags: ansible

I want to make the most of variable precedence with ansible.

So let’s have a look at this simplified project:

```
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│   └── web
├── hosts
│   └── local
└── site.yml
```

The inventory file `hosts/local`:

```
[local_web]
192.168.1.20

[local_db]
192.168.1.20

[web:children]
local_web

[db:children]
local_db
```

The `group_vars/all` file:

```
test: ALL
```

The `group_vars/web` file:

```
test: WEB
```

The `site.yml` file:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: db
  tasks:
    - debug: var=test
```

Alright, so this is just to test variable precedence. As I run ansible in the `db` group, the `test` variable should display “ALL”, as ansible will only looks into `group_vars/all`, right?
**Wrong:**

```
TASK: [debug var=test] ******************************************************** 
ok: [192.168.1.20] => {
    "var": {
        "test": "WEB"
    }
}
```

Actually, if `local_web` and `local_db` hosts are different, then it works.

Why ansible still looks into an unrelated config file when hosts are the same? Is that a bug or just me?

Comment: Ansible is great except it has this kind of irking behavior.  The way I see it, hosts are variables too.  Why would a variable value somehow affects variable precedence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stating that `192.168.1.20` is a member of all 4 of your defined groups, and that's independent of how you reference the host in your playbook. No matter how you reference the host in your playbook Ansible is going to evaluate all the groups that host is in and import variables based on those groups.

Here's a handy test to demonstrate this:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: db
  tasks:
   - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }} is in group {{ item }}"
     when: inventory_hostname in groups[item]
     with_items: group_names
```

The output of this is:

```
TASK: [debug msg="host is in group {{ item }}"]     *******************************
ok: [192.168.1.20] => (item=db) => {
    "item": "db",
    "msg": "192.168.1.20 is in group db"
}
ok: [192.168.1.20] => (item=local_db) => {
    "item": "local_db",
    "msg": "192.168.1.20 is in group local_db"
}
ok: [192.168.1.20] => (item=local_web) => {
    "item": "local_web",
    "msg": "192.168.1.20 is in group local_web"
}
ok: [192.168.1.20] => (item=web) => {
    "item": "web",
    "msg": "192.168.1.20 is in group web"
}
```

Since the host is in the `web` group then the `web` group_vars file was included.

Comment: So, I understand that ansible looks at the host **before** looking at the group. In this very case, it sees the host 192.168.1.20 and, because it’s inside all the groups, it loads all configuration files. Is that right? Then, is there a way to organize the inventory file in order to make ansible NOT load the web config file in this case? Now I understand how it works, but the way it does don’t looks adequate. I mean, with this exemple I’m “stating that 192.168.1.20 is a member of all 4”, but with two different hosts, it is not true anymore...

Comment: If you want to include variables outside of the way in which Ansible implicitly includes them then you should take a look at the [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/include_vars_module.html) task. Using that (and perhaps some custom 'when' logic, etc.) you can customize how facts/vars are utilized.

Answer (score 1):

@Bruce P answer is right.

However, this ansible behavior is not satisfying for me, because it change variable precedence depending on the hosts. Instead of `group_vars`, I use the `vars_files` dict.

I moved `group_vars` into a directory named `vars`.

The updated `site.yml`:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: db
  tasks:
    - debug: var=test
  vars_files:
    - vars/all
    - vars/db
```

Now, `test` displays “ALL”, as I wanted. It first read `vars/all`, then `vars/db` (which is empty).

(Note: variable precedence seems to be a bit [buggy](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11382) at the moment - v1.9.2 -. This means if you use variables as var files name, ansible will not load files in the order expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that can leave variables in group_vars is to replace the inventory file hosts/local by two files : hosts/inv_db and hosts/inv_web, and to use the -i option to specify the inventory file to use.